# How to overload & (and) clauses filtering Numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

*pseudo i.e.*:

```
A = np.array(...)

conditions = [(A > 1), (A < 2)]                         # how to do something like these?

filtered = A[&(condition for condition in conditions)]  #
```

With few conditions, it's ok to go by, for example,  `filtered = A[(A > 1) & (A < 2)]`; though is it possible to do so in a more scalable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try [`np.logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) with an [unpacking operator](https://towardsdatascience.com/unpacking-operators-in-python-306ae44cd480) on the list of conditions.

```
arr = np.random.random((10,))
conditions = [arr>0.2, arr**2<=0.5] #list of conditions
arr[np.logical_and(*conditions)]    #unpack conditions inside logical_and with *
```

```
array([0.33208271, 0.22984103, 0.58209428, 0.37531787, 0.69639457])
```